# Moving from Sense Queries To Visual Studio Queries

Tags: c#, visual-studio, elasticsearch, nest, sense

I have been using sense to run Elasticsearch queries, I have found it easy to use as there is lots of information online.

But how do I now run these queries on somewhere like visual studio, in C# any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use Nest library in .Net

Documentation : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/2.x/index.html

Github : https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net

Nuget : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nest